# How does the NPM package guarantee long-term correctness?

Tags: npm

NPM packages can't lock their dependencies(and dependencies' dependencies), for example:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "someDep": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

`my-package@1.0.0` depends on `someDep@^1.2.3` now.

If someday `someDep` upgrades to `1.9.0`, and I run `npm install my-package@1.0.0` in a project without `package.lock` or `yarn.lock`, `someDep@1.9.0` will be installed.

Maybe some breaking changes were introduced between `someDep@1.2.3` and `someDep@1.9.0`, they will cause `my-package@1.0.0` to be broken.

If I set `someDep`'s version to be fixed on `1.2.3` like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "someDep": "1.2.3"
  }
}
```

I can surely lock the version of `someDep` to be 1.2.3, but I can't force `someDep`'s dependencies to be also fixed so that they can break me down too.

What can we do to guarantee the long-term correctness of NPM packages?

Comment: [`bundleDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bundleddependencies) and distribute the zip file.